# mysql fulltext search natural language mode vs boolean mode accuracy

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have items table of online store, which has fulltext index on item_title, item_description, item_category columns. I would like to write search script, but having problem with deciding in which mode to search (natural language or boolean mode). Let's say user searches for `intel core i5 notebooks`. If I set natural language mode in search script user will not be able to search for query `intel core i5 notebooks -apple`. Can anybody explain me the difference between natural language mode and boolean mode? Which is more accurate?

Comment: What do you need to know in addition to the information provided [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the difference in scoring for example

Comment: The information on that page seems to suggest that there *isn't* any change in scoring.  Your decision on which to use should be based on whether or not you need the Boolean mode features.

Comment: sphinxsearch is what you are looking for.

Comment: @beck03076 I am on shared hosting ;)

Answer (score 4):

***Natural Language Full-Text Search** vs **Boolean Full-Text Search***

**Natural Language Full-Text Search**: It considers all the text in the search keywords as it is naturally with no characters holding special meaning.

For instance, `intel core i5 notebooks -apple` IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE would return all matches that contain `intel`, `core`, `i5`, `notebooks`, and `-apple`.

**Boolean Full-Text Search**: Some characters have a special meaning. Examples are: `+`, `-`, `*`. In your case, `intel core i5 notebooks -apple` IN BOOLEAN MODE would return all matches that contain `intel`, `core`, `i5`, and `notebooks`. In the matches to be found `apple` **must not** be included. The `-` sign has a special meaning and it will not be considered as regular/natural text.

Back to your question: **Which is more accurate?**

It depends on the results you want to get. If you want `apple` to be present in your results then you may use 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE'.

If you do not want `apple` in your results, then use 'IN BOOLEAN MODE'.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the difference is between [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

And in your case, I can say you need boolean mode

`'+"intel core i5 notebooks" -apple'`